# Save ggplot with a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a function to save plots (from `ggplot`).

Here is a data frame:

```
### creating data frame
music <- c("Blues", "Hip-hop", "Jazz", "Metal", "Rock")
number <- c(8, 7, 4, 6, 11)
df.music <- data.frame(music, number)
colnames(df.music) <- c("Music", "Amount")
```

Then I create a plot:

```
### creating bar graph (this part is OK)
myplot <- ggplot(data=df.music, aes(x=music, y=number)) +
 geom_bar(stat="identity") +
 xlab(colnames(df.music)[1]) +
 ylab(colnames(df.music)[2]) +
 ylim(c(0,11)) +
 ggtitle("Ulubiony typ muzyki wśród studentów")
```

Now I want to save this plot to `.pdf`.

This works:

```
pdf("Myplot.pdf", width=5, height=5)
plot.music.bad
dev.off()
```

However I would like to automate this with a function which takes as an argument the plot I want to save.
I don't know exactly how to do it; here's what I have tried:

```
save <- function(myplot){
  plot<- myplot
  pdf("lol.pdf", width=5, height=5)
  plot
  dev.off()
}
### .pdf file is created but doesn't work
save(myplot)
```

So, how can I do it?

Comment: did you try `ggsave` ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use `print()` to save plots produced from `ggplot2` to a file.

First, define your function to save plots:

```
savePlot <- function(myPlot) {
        pdf("myPlot.pdf")
        print(myPlot)
        dev.off()
}
```

Create your plot:

```
 myPlot <- ggplot(ggplot(data=df.music, aes(x=music, y=number)) +
 geom_bar(stat="identity") +
 xlab(colnames(df.music)[1]) +
 ylab(colnames(df.music)[2]) +
 ylim(c(0,11)) +
 ggtitle("Ulubiony typ muzyki wśród studentów")
```

And finally call the function:

```
savePlot(myPlot)
```

---

Alternatively, you could just use `ggsave()` after creating your plot:

```
ggsave(filename="myPlot.pdf", plot=myPlot)
```

Answer (score 17):

Following was useful for me, may be for someone else as well. One can save the last plot without explicitly referring it as well.

```
ggsave("filename.pdf",  # jpg, png, eps, tex, etc.
       plot = last_plot(), # or an explicit ggplot object name,
       width = 7, height = 5, 
       units = "in", # other options c("in", "cm", "mm"), 
       dpi = 300)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you would like an image file instead of a pdf, also the following works

```
ggsave(filename="myPlot.jpg", plot=last_plot())
```

or with additional parameters, as follows.

```
ggsave(filename="myPlot.jpg", plot=lastplot(),
       width = 10, height = 5, 
       units = "cm", # other options are "in", "cm", "mm" 
       dpi = 200
       )
```

Also following file types are supported "eps", "ps", "tex" (pictex), "pdf", "jpeg", "tiff", "png", "bmp", "svg" or "wmf".